# how to set radio button same value if same name attr

Tags: jquery, selector, onchange

how to set same value when radio button onchange(when select someone radiobutton)

```
<body>

    <label>slect color:</label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="logic_01">YES</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="logic_01">NO</label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="logic_02">YES</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="logic_02">NO</label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="logic_03">YES</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="logic_03">NO</label>
<script>
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        $(this).attr("value","SS")
    })     
</script>    

</body>
```

for example select name logic_01 then

```
<label><input type="radio" name="logic_01" value="logic_01">YES</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="logic_01" value="logic_01>NO</label>
```

Comment: What's the point of radio buttons where they both have the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an attribute selector that selects all radio buttons with the current name.

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    $(`:radio[name=${this.name}]`).val("SS");
});
```

Comment: Thanks you first !! your code is perfect !! And if i want to put the funciton on  document.ready   how can i advance to adjust?

Comment: The same way you do anything else: `$(document).ready(function() { above code })`

Comment: you so nice an strong (it seems more Moustache guy is expert like   https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/23397017)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the radio input in the wrong way, your inputs should have the same name with different value to capture if they were selected:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="logic" value="logic_01">Logic 1</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="logic" value="logic_02">Logic 2</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="logic" value="logic_03">Logic 3</label>
```

Comment: in normal situation , you are right Ali ,but on now my meet a situation will send radio button value to json file , in mean time our myradio button from dynamic generate